# Строка записывается в файл с переносом

Tags: python-3.x

```
with open("accounts.txt",'a') as f:
    f.write(f"{current_email}:{phone_number}:{user_pass}\n")
```

При записи в файл почему-то получается 2 строки вместо одной. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Либо не заканчивать записываемые данные символом переноса строки, либо открывать файл в бинарном режиме, чтобы этот символ не добавлялся автоматически.